# QGLWidget + QGraphicsScene + QGraphicsView problem

Tags: c++, qt4

I would like to create a simple thumbnail viewer using QGLWidget, QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView. And I have a problem with placing QGLWidget on QGraphicsScene. The code is similar to this:

```
QGraphicsScene *testScene = new QGraphicsScene (0, 0, 400, 400, 0);

QGLWidget *testWidget1 = new QGLWidget();
testWidget1->renderText("Test text1");

QGLWidget *testWidget2 = new QGLWidget();
testWidget2->renderText("Test text2");

testScene->addWidget(testWidget1);
testScene->addWidget(testWidget2);

QGraphicsView *testView = new QGraphicsView();
testView->setScene(testScene);
testView->show()
```

It is possible to place few QGLWidgets on QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView? Where I doing something wrong? Is there any other component on which I could embed QGLWidgets and show them on the screen?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QGraphicsScene::addWidget documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) states that `QGLWidget` is not a supported widget type.

Parenting a `QGLWidget` onto the viewport of the `QGraphicsView` doesn't seem to work either.

**Edit:**

Actually parenting a `QGLWidget` to the viewport does work provided I put the `renderText` call within the `paintGL` method of my test GL widget.

Answer (score 2):

To make QGLWidget show in QGraphicsView, you should redirect painting for it. You can overwrite the paintGL like this:

```
virtual void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    QGLWidget::paintGL();
    //support redirecting painting
    QPaintDevice* device = QPainter::redirected(this);
    if (device != NULL && device != this)
    {
        QImage image = grabFrameBuffer();
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawImage(QPointF(0.0,0.0),image);
    }
}
```

It works well for most platforms, but still happens to show black widget.

Answer (score 0):

From the [QGraphicsView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html) docs:

> To render using OpenGL, simply call `setViewport(new QGLWidget)`. QGraphicsView takes ownership of the viewport widget.

So, in order to draw text on the view, use a [QGraphicsTextItem](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicstextitem.html) rather than trying to draw text using the `QGLWidget`.